# XPath. Child has a default namespace, how to get its elements?

Tags: xml, xpath, namespaces

How to get the element of `CCC`? Xpath sees only the `s:Envelope` and `s:Body`.

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <s:Body>
        <BBB xmlns="https://services">
            <CCC>test</CCC>
        </BBB>
    </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the namespace context for your XPath expression contains the namespace bindings

```
s = http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/
t = https://services
```

then the XPath expression

```
/s:Envelope/s:Body/t:BBB/t:CCC
```

will find the CCC element.

The way in which you establish namespace bindings depends on the XPath API you are using.

Comment: The namespace context for my XPath expression not contains the namespace binding
`t = https://services`
in this issue

Comment: I can not add it, the answer is a third-party service

Comment: @GlebBelyaev Michael Kay is saying to add it to your XPath processor, not to the source XML.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
/s:Envelope/s:Body/*:BBB/*:CCC
```

Comment: Here's another way to `//*[local-name()='CCC']`